Wie lauten die weiblichen Entsprechungen zu "Mannesalter" und "Mannesjahre"?
Es gibt die Begriffe Mannesalter und Mannesjahre für das männliche Erwachsenenalter. Gibt es für diese Begriffe weibliche Entsprechungen?

Da dieses Wort laut DWDS eindeutig in die 1960er Jahre gehört, ist die Antwort ebenfalls eine aus diesem Jahrzehnt:
Es gehört sich nicht, nach dem Alter einer Dame zu fragen.
Ernsthaft: diese Begrifflichkeiten sind Ausdruck eines spezifischen geschlechtlichen Habitus. Das Mannesalter erreichen bedeutete darin, dass jungen Männer mit Erreichen des Erwachsenenalters erlaubt wurde, eine öffentliche Stellung einzunehmen. In seinen besten Mannesjahren gestaltete ein Mann seine Lebenswelt aktiv.
Insofern is ein entsprechender Begriff für Frauen nicht erforderlich, da für sie das Konzept "gesellschaftliche Verantwortung" oder "gestalterische Kraft" nicht vorgesehen waren. Ausdruck für das Erreichen des Erwachsenenalters war also bestenfalls ein heiratsfähiges Alter erreichen. Sollten sie dennoch, da in der Zeit nach dem zweiten Weltkrieg die Zahl der Männer so begrenzt war, in eine eigenständige Rolle gedrängt sein, so sagte man von ihnen

Sie steht ihren Mann.

Sollte sie, Gott bewahre!, selbst den Willen bekundet haben, sich keinem  Mann unterzuordnen, so wurde sie als

männisch, ein Mannweib

verunglimpft.

Diese polemische Antwort versucht keinesfalls, eine reale Periode der deutschen Geschichte zu beschreiben. Vielmehr umreißt sie einen Gedankenkontext und einen Habitus, in dem die Verwendung des Begriffes "Mannesalter" einen Sinn ergab. Die 1960er Jahre wahren vermutlich das letzte Jahrzehnt, in dem eine Bezugnahme auf dieses Gesellschaftsbild mehrheitsfähig war und öffentliche Gegenwehr kein größeres Forum fand.

Auch DWDS: https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=dta%2Bdwds&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0.05&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1600%3A1999&q1=Mannesalter D.h. Der Ausdruck ist eher einer des 19. Jhdt als der 1960er.

+1, alles völlig richtig. Rein linguistisch gesehen wäre die weibliche Entsprechung zur Unterscheidung "Knabe - Mann" einfach "Mädchen/Mädel - Frau" und könnte entsprechende Komposita bilden, was sie aber aus den angeführten Gründen nicht getan hat.

@KilianFoth: "Rein linguistisch" gesehen ist die Entsprechung zu "Knabe-Mann" eigentlich "Maid-Weib", nämlich "unverheiratete Frau-verheiratete Frau". Das Wort, von dem "Mädchen" der Diminutiv ist, ist nämlich "Maid" (aus dem ursprünglichen "Magd"), das Wort "Weib" bezeichnet die verheiratete Frau (siehe englisch "wife"). Auf Althochdeutsch lautete die Bezeichnung der Frau "cuen" (vgl. engl "queen"), die des Mannes "wer" (vgl "wergeld", "werwolf", ...), denn daß "Man(n)" nichtr mehr "Mensch jedweden Geschlechts", sondern "männlicher Mensch" bedeutet, ist sehr neu.

"Mädchenjahre einer Königin", Film aus dem Jahr 1954, nach einer Vorlage von 1932. Der würde wohl nicht so geheißen haben, wenn es das Wort nicht gegeben hätte, oder?

@bakunin Beim Blättern in Korpusbelegen bin ich gerade auf einen Text von Hermann Löns (Mein Braunes Buch, 1907) gestoßen, der "Mädchenjahre" mit "Frauenzeit" kontrastiert. Als ich diesen Begriff gesucht habe, stellte sich heraus, das er zuvor genau einmal nachgewiesen wird: in einem Kräuter-Kompendium aus dem Jahr 1690 als Euphemismus für die weibliche Regelblutung.

Eine vergleichbare Formulierung, die auch auf Frauen angewendet wird oder wurde, ist "in der Blüte seiner/ihrer Jahre". Auch "in den besten Jahren" oder "die besten Jahre" kann geschlechtsunabhängig genutzt werden.
Was es nicht gibt, ist sowas wie "im besten Frauenalter". Das hätte  vor 100 Jahren geradezu obszön geklungen. Und würde, wenn man ehrlich ist, selbst in der heutigen Gesellschaft immer noch falsch klingen, weil es bei Frauen weiterhin in erster Linie mit körperlicher Attraktivität und deren Höhepunkt in sehr jungen Jahren assoziiert würde.

"in den besten Jahren" wird jedoch meistens für eine Lebensphase genützt, die, um im Bild zu bleiben, eher der Ernte als der Blüte entspricht. Also finanzstarke Ältere am Ende der Berufskarriere oder am Beginn des Ruhestandes – vgl. den Anglizismus Best Ager.
